# Angular JS uppercase not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code not working. directly print {{ name | uppercase }}..

can you help me out.

```js
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
    <body ng-app="myApp">
    <p>Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name">
    </p>
    <h3>{{ name | uppercase }}</h3>
```

Comment: The reason being is, you have provided `myApp` in `ng-app` directive.. so angular looks for `myApp` module in loaded JS.. and it didn't find it, so angular threw an error.. Please check console.. **Solution** *Either defined angular module `myApp` in script **OR** keep `ng-app=""` (not preferred way, but you can try for testing)*

Comment: Yes. working. Thank you mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **ng-controller** is missing

Try this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="caseCtrl">
<input type="text" ng-model="txt" />
<h3>{{txt | uppercase}}</h3>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('caseCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.txt = "Hello World!";
});
</script>
```